# Which is fastest? Count in subquery or with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

Which is fastest/most efficient? Both work.

Solution 1. Grouping by the id:

```
SELECT
    *, 
    COUNT(*) AS pages 
FROM
    notis 
WHERE
    cid = 20 
GROUP BY
    n.id
ORDER BY
    nid DESC
```

Solution 2. Count in a subquery:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (select count(*) FROM notis WHERE cid=20) AS count
FROM
    notis
WHERE
    cid = 20
ORDER BY
    nid DESC
```

Comment: Downvoter: Reason why you don't like my curious question would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: These don't look like they would produce equivalent output.

Comment: The first one is invalid (standard) SQL and instead of rejecting it MySQL will return random data instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Solution 1 is Best and fast: 
because solution 2 have subquery

BUT you have to change your query like that:

```
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS pages 
  FROM notis 
  WHERE cid = 20 
  GROUP BY nid
  ORDER BY nid DESC
```

you changed the place of GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

Idont know if you looking for count(`*`) or you want count by every `nid` . if count(`*`) then consider to not use GROUP BY

```
 SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS pages 
 FROM notis 
 WHERE cid = 20 
 ORDER BY nid DESC
```

Comment: The `group by` usage is invalid (standard) SQL and instead of rejecting it MySQL will prefer to random results instead: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . It is more accurate to say that this use of the group by extension results in *arbitrary* values from matching rows.  Randomness is a very hard property to come by, actually.  (The documentation uses the word "indeterminate", http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html.)